# Correct way for waiting for all children in real application

Tags: c, linux, process, posix, wait

I'm writing a multi-threading application(school project, modified river crossing problem). 
I'm using POSIX semaphores, shared memory and fork function. Main process creates 2 processes. Each of them then creates N processes. Each process represent a single person. I'd like to know what is the professional technique/the best approach for parent to wait for all of his children till they finish and then obtain their exit code. I don't/can't use constructions like:

```
while (wait(NULL) > 0)
    ;
// parent code
```

Neither constructions using shared variable like

```
while (1)
    if (num_of_processes == num_of_finished_processes)
        break;
// parent_code
```

NOTE: num_of_processes is argument passed to program

Can I somehow use semaphore to tell parent: "now wake up and execute your code".
In one sentence. I don't want to use active/cyclic waiting.
Thank you for any suggestion. I'm just beginner in this field.

Comment: You could increment a semaphore on child processes before exiting (or register a dtor function (executed just before really exiting)). And in the main process, you would try decrementing it (blocking the semaphore while a process increments it) and use a child_exited_counter. Or just use signals

Comment: Can you explain the reason you can't use `wait()`? I ask, because you asked for a professional technique.

Comment: Professional technique, is function wait in loop? In project specification is don't use active waiting for IPC.

Comment: Calling wait() (or waitpid()) as necessary is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of "professional" can be elastic.

There are basically two reasons to reap your children: avoid zombies taking up room in the process table and to interrogate the children return codes and (presumably) base some action on them.  Both of these *may* point to, all things being equal, reaping them as quickly as possible.

So your options are:

1. have the parent block waiting for them with `wait` or `waitpid`.
2. periodically poll for them with `waitpid` and the WNOHANG option
3. have the SIGCHLD signal delivered and handle them as they arise
4. have the SIGCHLD signal delivered and use `signalfd` (on linux) but this still requires polling or the use of `select/poll/epoll`

Since you have rejected 1 & 2 (and implicitly 4) that leaves dealing with the signal and using a handler.  For mental health reasons, if not necessarily professionalism, most people avoid signals as much as they can and don't go looking for ways to deal with them if they don't have to do so because:

1. signal handlers come with their own constraints, primarily that you want to be in and out of them as quickly as possible and there are limited number async-safe functions you should employ within them.  So that usually means recording whatever you can inside the handler and dealing with the information when you can in the main program or a thread dedicated to it.
2. Since you have specifically invited a signal (SIGCHLD) into your life by choosing to handle it, you have bear the consequences of you system calls being interrupted.  Since you are using POSIX semaphores then `sem_wait` would be of particular concern.  You can get around *most* of this by just turning on the SA_RESTART flag via your `sigaction` call when establishing your handler but even with the flag there are a number of calls which are not automatically restarted.
3. Multi-threading and signals come with their own set of headaches.

Below is a crude but illustrative example of some of the above issues:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct childInfo
{
    pid_t childPid;
      int childstatus;

} childInfo;

static volatile sig_atomic_t numberOfChildren = 0;
static volatile sig_atomic_t childrenReaped = 0;

childInfo *childrenTable;

void saveStatus(pid_t pid, int status)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildren; ++i)
    {
        if (pid == childrenTable[i].childPid)
            childrenTable[i].childstatus = status;
    }
}

void printChildrenStatus()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildren; ++i)
    {
        if (childrenTable[i].childPid != 0)
        {
            if (WIFEXITED(childrenTable[i].childstatus))
                printf("PID %d exited normally.  "
                       "Exit status: %d\n",
                        childrenTable[i].childPid, WEXITSTATUS(childrenTable[i].childstatus));
            else
                if (WIFSTOPPED(childrenTable[i].childstatus))
                    printf("PID %d was stopped by %d\n",
                           childrenTable[i].childPid,
                           WSTOPSIG(childrenTable[i].childstatus));
                else
                    if (WIFSIGNALED(childrenTable[i].childstatus))
                        printf("PID %d exited due to signal %d\n.",
                               childrenTable[i].childPid,
                               WTERMSIG(childrenTable[i].childstatus));

            childrenTable[i].childPid = 0;
            childrenReaped++;
        }
    }
}

void childHandler(int signum)
{
      int childstatus;
    pid_t childpid;

    while ((childpid = waitpid( -1, &childstatus, WNOHANG)) > 0)
        saveStatus(childpid, childstatus);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
       numberOfChildren = atoi(argv[1]);
    else
    {
        printf("must enter num of children to create...");
        exit(1);
    }

    childrenTable = calloc(numberOfChildren, sizeof(childInfo));

    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_handler = childHandler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART; // Restart functions, particularly your parent's
                              // sem_wait if interrupted by the handler
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildren; ++i)
    {
       pid_t pid = fork();

       if (pid)
           childrenTable[i].childPid = pid;
       else
       {
           sleep(i);
           exit(0);
       }
    }

    while(numberOfChildren - childrenReaped)
    {
        pause();
        printChildrenStatus();
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( wait(NULL) > 0 )
```

is an infine loop, because the return value of `wait(2)` is the pid of the terminated - child process, which is `!= 0`, and won't change.

If you want the parent - process to wait for `N` processes to exit you can simply use a loop like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    wait(NULL);
```

Comment: Where there is no child wait() should return -1. No?

Comment: @user3463614 Only `0` is `false` in C.